# Create CSS file that @imports other CSS files using gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-imports

I have a gulp task to split a CSS file to multiple CSS files (because of the 4095 selectors limitation for IE 6-9) using `gulp-sakugawa`.

Original CSS:

```
app.css
```

Split CSS:

```
app_1.css
app_2.css
app_3.css
etc...
```

I need to `@import` these split files into a newly created CSS file     `style.css`, something like below:

```
@import url('app_1.css');
@import url('app_2.css');
@import url('app_3.css');
//etc...
```

How can I do this in the following task?

```
gulp.task('splitCSS', function() {
  gulp.src(config.baseDir + '/assets/css/app.css')
    .pipe(gulpSakugawa({
       maxSelectors: 4000,
       mediaQueries: 'separate',
       suffix: '_'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.baseDir + '/assets/css/split'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses [`through2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) to collect all the files in the stream and then emit a single file `style.css` that contains `@import` statements for all the files:

```
var through2 = require('through2');
var path = require('path');

function createCssImports() {
  var lastFile, files = [];
  return through2.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
    files.push(path.basename(file.path));
    cb(null, lastFile = file);
  }, function (cb) {
    var file = lastFile.clone();
    file.contents = new Buffer(files.map(function(f) {
      return "@import url('" + f + "');"
    }).join('\n'));
    file.path = path.join(path.dirname(file.path), 'style.css');
    this.push(file);
    cb();
  });
}

gulp.task('splitCss', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.baseDir + '/assets/css/app.css')
     .pipe(gulpSakugawa({
        maxSelectors: 4000,
        mediaQueries: 'separate',
        suffix: '_'
     }))
     .pipe(createCssImports())
     .pipe(gulp.dest(config.baseDir + '/assets/css/split'));
});
```